# How to force std::map::find() to search by value

Tags: c++

From what I have deduced, the std::map::find() method searches the map by comparising pointer address instead of values. Example:

```
std::string aa = "asd";
const char* a = aa.c_str();
const char* b = "asd";
// m_options is a std::map<const char*, int )
m_options.insert( std::make_pair( a, 0 ) );
if( m_options.find( b ) != m_options.end() ) {
    // won't reach this place
}
```

I am kinda surprised (because I am using primitive types instead of some class) and I think that I have done something wrong, if not then how to force it to use value instead of address?

Comment: Can't you use an `std::map<std::string, int>`?

Comment: I can, but I don't want to.

Comment: @tobi: You should want to :)

Comment: @tobi Then you have to write a custom comparator `std::map<const char*, int, comparator>`

Comment: You shouldn't be going around deducing anything - the behaviour of standard library containers is, well, *standardized*. So you can just look it up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using `char *` as a key type for the map. For the pointer types, comparison is performed by their address (as the `map` cannot know that these pointers are NULL-terminated 8-bit strings).

To achieve your goal, you could create the `map` with custom `compare` function, e.g.:

```
bool MyStringCompare(const char *s1, const char *s2) { 
  return strcmp(s1, s2) < 0; 
}
...
std::map<const char*, int, MyStringCompare> m_options;
```

Or consider using `std::string` as the key type.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, map uses a strict ordering comparison operator to look for values, not the equality operator. Anyway, you can achieve this by passing a custom functor that compares the values of the strings, or do the right thing and use `std::string` instead.